# gwt HorizontalSplitPanel: catch split position event

Tags: gwt, split

I use a HorizonSplitPanel in gwt and wonder if there is no possibility to get an event, if the split position is changed. I need the event to later manually change the positions of some absolute positioned elements.

Is there a possibility to get an event for the change of the split position? Or does somebody know a work-around?

Best,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may sink mouseup/mousedown event on the splitPanel, and check split position at each mouse release. If it has changed since last time, then fire a custom event.

You also may override newer SplitLayoutPanel with your own Splitter implementation which sends a custom event on resize, since event handing is implemented in abstract Splitter class.

Comment: Thank you for your help. With the following code snippet it works perfect: 
SplitLayoutPanel splitLayoutPanel = new SplitLayoutPanel() {
      @Override
      public void onResize() {
          super.onResize();
          System.out.println("onResize");
      }           
  };